# Need help understanding how to store twitter trend in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, twitter

I'm trying to learn MongoDB and perform Twitter analysis. So, as a test, I was trying to get the data for twitter trend as explained here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/trends/place

So far, I was able to insert the trends data into mongodb, however, I'm confused now regarding other objects in the JSON returned from twitter such as location, as_of, and created_at. How do I store them in mongodb? I created a collection called trends and looped through the JSONObject in java to insert to the database, but how do I add the others in and can I make reference to the collection if I have to create other collections to store these info? I did some google search, but still had some confusion trying to understand. This is the first time I'm using mongodb for my Master's project, and I'm really confused since I'm used to SQL. Any help regarding logic and walkthrough is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if you want to access the location,as-of and created_at then u can add these fields to the trends itself like this. Then u can filter it using those fields if needed,

```
"trends": [
 {
        "events": null, 
        "name": "#GanaPuntosSi", 
        "promoted_content": null, 
        "query": "%23GanaPuntosSi", 
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search/?q=%23GanaPuntosSi",
"locations": [
      {
        "name": "Worldwide", 
        "woeid": 1
      }
    ],"as_of": "2012-08-24T23:25:43Z", 
    "created_at": "2012-08-24T23:24:14Z", 
      },
 {
        "events": null, 
        "name": "#GanaPuntosSi", 
        "promoted_content": null, 
        "query": "%23GanaPuntosSi", 
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search/?q=%23GanaPuntosSi",
"locations": [
      {
        "name": "Worldwide", 
        "woeid": 1
      }
    ],"as_of": "2012-08-24T23:25:43Z", 
    "created_at": "2012-08-24T23:24:14Z", 
      }

]
```

For each trend field add the three fields as well.

Comment: @malik Thanks for the reply, but I'm still somewhat confused visualizing the structure in the database. So, trends is a collection and contains these attributes. but what becomes of the locations since locations has 2 other attributes?

Comment: Location would be an array just like trends having different objects. As of now there is only one object but there may be cases where there are more than one object like this "locations": [
      {
        "name": "Worldwide", 
        "woeid": 1
      },{
        "name": "Worldwide", 
        "woeid": 1
      }
    ]

Comment: So, if I insert it to the document, will mongoDB understand?